# sorting algorithm is not working

Tags: java, generics, sorting, set

I need to sort in ascending order as I add object to my generic class (I'm using strings).

I'm using selection sort, but it is not working.

I don't know if it is the correct way of doing this, so would appreciate the input.

#### OrderSet class

```
public class OrderSet<T extends Comparable> implements Set<T> {

    private T[] items;
    private int size;

    public OrderSet()
    {
        items = (T[]) new Comparable[5];        
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T s)
    {
        if(size >= items.length)
        {
            items = grow(items);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
        {
            if(items[i] == null)
            {
                items[i] = s;
                size++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(size > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < size; j++)
                {
                    T tmp;
                    if (items[i].compareTo(items[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        tmp = items[i];
                        items[i] = items[j];
                        items[j] = tmp;
                    }                    
                }                
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {        
        for(T a : items)
        { 
            if(a != null)
                System.out.print(a+", ");            
        }
    }

    public T[] grow(T[] a)
    {
        T[] newA = (T[]) new Comparable[a.length+5];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newA, 0, a.length);
        return newA;
    }

}
```

#### main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        OrderSet<String> s1 = new OrderSet<>();
        WordCount s2 = new WordCount();

        Scanner input = new Scanner("the boy plays in the park with dog");
        while (input.hasNext()) 
        {
            String w = input.next();
            s1.add(w);
        }

        s1.show();

        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've written it like this? A simpler way would be to add your strings into a List<String> and then use Collection.sort() to sort them. There are two sort() methods, one of them takes a Comparator so you can sort in whatever fashion you like.

Comment: for that I would have to change my array of type T[] instead... and use a List. Is that what you mean?

Comment: `T extends Comparable` does not guarantee that `items[i].compareTo(items[j])` will work. And it's bad to use raw types. You should use `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: why would not guarantee to work?

Comment: @miatech, see this: http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node180.html, this is why generics can be very dangerous and you have to be very careful with your typing.

Comment: @miatech - actually I was thinking along the lines of scrapping what you have done! If you are trying to sort strings just create an ArrayList<String>, add your values and then call Collections.sort(yourList) at the point you need them sorted. If you need them in any other order (i.e reverse order) then you'll find that the sort() method is overloaded and you can pass a Comparator<String> into that, suitably written to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be doing is a bubble sort as you add in items, the generic form of a selection sort is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length - 1; i++)
{
   int smallest = i;
   for(int j = i + 1; j< arr.length; j++)
   {
       if(arr[j].compareTo(arr[smallest]) > 0)
           smallest = j;
   }
   if(smallest < arr.length && smallest != i)
       swap(arr[i], arr[smallest]);
}
```

You could do it swapping the largest into the last index, but this should work as well. Note, swap is just a placeholder psuedocode for the actual swapping.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's your Sort Algorithm that is wrong. Ardentsonata is right, you use a Bubblesort algorithm but there is a mistake:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < size; j++){
        T tmp;
        if (items[i].compareTo(items[j]) > 0) {
            tmp = items[i];
            items[i] = items[j];
            items[j] = tmp;
        }                    
    }                
}
```

The Problem is the start value of the second loop, you want to check if any other element - except the ones you already sorted is bigger than the element you want to sort at the moment. 
So your second loop needs this head:

```
for(int j = (i+1); j < size; j++)
```

so you really sort the array.

Otherwise you were uncontrollable switching your values aroung, because after you switched something to the second slot you switch it back in the next iteration.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Use **java.util.TreeSet< T >**, which implements **SortedSet< T >**.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use String compare concept in this case

```
class City {

public static void main (String args[])
{ 
int i,j;
String temp;
String s[] = new String[6];
for(i=0; i<6; i++)
 s[i]=args[i];
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
  for(j=0;j<6-i-1;j++){
 if(s[j].compareTo(s[j+1])>0)
 {
   temp=s[j];
   s[j]=s[j+1];
   s[j+1]=temp;
 } 
}
 }
 for(i=0; i<6; i++)
 {
 System.out.println(s[i]);
}
}}
```